# Gap filling seasonal data (missing data imputation) Kalman filter in R

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, kalman-filter, imputets

I am trying to gap-fill weather data, my data is half-hourly, but here I prepared a reproducible code for hourly data. Because the weather data is seasonal, first I create a time series using stat::ts() and then I feed that to Kalman filter (imputeTS::na_seadec) or forecast::na.interp, however, the code is very slow while if I feed the raw data to kalam filter without created ts it is pretty fast but it loses the seasonality information. Also, I tried find_frequency = TRUE in imputeTS::na_seadec(), again it makes the code too slow (it takes hours and hours for a single time series). I wonder if there is a way to use Kalman filter but preserve the seasonality information.

```
library(riem)
library(dplyr)
library(imputeTS)
library(forecast)
library(stats)
library(plotly)

Raw_data =riem_measures("SFO", date_start = "2010-01-01")

Gapfilled <- Raw_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(tmpfts = ts(data = .$tmpf,
                                   start = min(time(valid)),
                                   frequency = 24)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ts_interpFilled = forecast::na.interp(tmpfts) %>% as.numeric(),
                na_seadecKalman = imputeTS::na_seadec(tmpfts, algorithm = "kalman"),
                na_seadecma = imputeTS::na_seadec(tmpf, algorithm = "ma"),
                #              na_kalman = imputeTS::na_kalman(tmpfts, model = "auto.arima"),
                tsclean = forecast::tsclean (tmpfts) %>% as.numeric()
  )


plot_ly(Gapfilled, x = ~valid) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~ tmpf, name = 'Actuals',mode = 'lines', type  = 'scatter' ) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~ts_interpFilled, name = 'forecast::na.interp', mode = 'lines', type  = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~na_seadecma, name = 'imputeTS::na_seadecma', mode = 'lines', type  = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~tsclean, name = 'forecast::tsclean', mode = 'lines', type  = 'scatter')  %>%
  # add_trace(y = ~na_kalman, name = 'imputeTS::na_kalman', mode = 'lines', type  = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~na_seadecKalman, name = 'imputeTS::na_seadecKalman', mode = 'lines', type  = 'scatter')
```

Comment: How many observations does one of your time series have?

Comment: I use 20 years of half-hourly data.

Comment: oh ok, don't think you can do anything there - that's just the amount of data where na.kalman is too slow